# Different member function for Different Non-Type Template Parameters

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, overloading

I have a `Vector` class and a `Matrix` class. I would like to implicitly convert a `Vector` class to a `Matrix` class using a `=` operator. The classes are defined as shown below.

```
template <unsigned int dim>
class Vector {
public:
  std::array<double, dim> x;
};

template <unsigned int nrow, unsigned int ncol>
class Matrix {
public:
  std::array<Vector<ncol>, nrow> x;

  auto& operator=(Vector<ncol> v)
  {
    x.fill(v);
    return *this;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Vector<2> vec1;
  vec1.x[0] = 1;
  vec1.x[1] = 2;

  Matrix<1, 2> mat1;
  mat1 = vec1;

  std::cout << mat1.x[0].x[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << mat1.x[0].x[1] << std::endl;
}
```

And this works correctly. However, I want to introduce another `operator=` which should work as show below.

```
auto& operator=(Vector<nrow> v)
{
  for(unsigned int row=0; row < nrow; ++row){
    x[row].x[0] = v[row];
  }
  return *this;
}
```

However, since the overloads instantiate to the same signature (for cases where `nrow=ncol`), I am not sure how to go about designing such a method. In specific, I wonder if it possible to define the second method only if `nrow!=ncol`.

I have tried using `std::enable_if` by defining two type

```
using nrow_t = std::integral_constant<unsigned int,nrow>;
using ncol_t = std::integral_constant<unsigned int,ncol>;
```

and then using `std::is_same`, but I am not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: `enable_if` looks like the straightforward way to fix the problem. What have you tried already?

Comment: I would reconsider the decision to use `operator=` to do this to avoid surprises for the un-aware programmer. Especially when the behavior depends on weather `nrow == ncol` or not.

Comment: i would strongly suggest using more meaningful function names instead of obtuse syntactic tricks. `fillByRow`, `fillByColumn`, `setRow`, and `setColumn` are a lot easier to understand than overloaded meaning of `operator=` depending the values of `nrow` and `ncol` of the `Matrix` and the `nrow` of the `Vector`.

Comment: After thinking about it, I agree wth @alain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a case where using a named function would be a lot easier.  It will convey exactly what is going on and not surprise anyone.  That said you can use something like this

```
template <unsigned int nrow, unsigned int ncol>
class Matrix {
public:
    std::array<Vector<ncol>, nrow> x;

    template<unsigned int cols,
             std::enable_if_t<cols == ncol || (cols == ncol && ncol == nrow)>* = nullptr>
    auto& operator=(Vector<cols> v)
    {
        x.fill(v);
        return *this;
    }
    template<unsigned int rows,
             std::enable_if_t<rows == nrow && nrow != ncol>* = nullptr>
    auto& operator=(Vector<rows> v)
    {
        for(unsigned int row=0; row < nrow; ++row){
            x[row].x[0] = v[row];
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

For the first overload we `enable_if` when `cols == ncol || (cols == ncol && ncol == nrow)` is true.  That will happen when it has the correct amount as the columns or the rows and columns are the same and it has the correct amount of columns.  The second overload uses `rows == nrow && nrow != ncol` and will only be active when the rows and columns are not the same and when the row amount matches.

Comment: I agree with your advice, still thanks for the solution.

Comment: @JayeshBadwaik No problem.  Glad to help.

Comment: this is a funny mix of C++11 and C++14. If you use C++14 features, you can avoid `typename std::enable_if<>::type` in favour of `std::enable_if_t<>`.

Comment: @Walter You're right.  I'm just so used to `name<>::type` I forget that there is the `name_t<>` types.  I'll update since this is clearly C++14.

Comment: I would have done it the other way around: get rid of the `auto` (`Matrix` isn't that much more to type, after all). I'd guess this would benefit compile times a bit (though I didn't test that)

Comment: @DanielJour Since C++14 is the current standard we should use that unless the OP requires otherwise.